TYPO3 v12.4 fluid_styled_content does not style content elements
I installed a TYPO3 v12.4 project with ddev and added 2 extensions that do not have much logic. I created a form and displayed it on the FE. That is mostly what I did with this project.
I wrote a short TypoScript to display the contentelements in FE and wanted to add my CSS and JS.
Here is the script:
# default page content
page = PAGE

page {
    includeCSS {
        pluginsCss = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/Css/plugins.css
        styleCss = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/Css/style.css
    }
    includeJS {
        customJs = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/JavaScript/custom.js
        jqueryJs = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/JavaScript/jquery.js
        pluginsJs = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/JavaScript/plugins.js
        plugins2Js = EXT:theme/Resources/Public/JavaScript/plugins2.js
    }
}

lib.dynamicContent = COA
lib.dynamicContent {
   10 = LOAD_REGISTER
   10.colPos.cObject = TEXT
   10.colPos.cObject {
      field = colPos
      ifEmpty.cObject = TEXT
      ifEmpty.cObject {
         value.current = 1
         ifEmpty = 0
      }
   }
   20 = CONTENT
   20 {
      table = tt_content
      select {
         orderBy = sorting
         where = {#colPos}={register:colPos}
         where.insertData = 1
      }
   }
   90 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}

# append content
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {
    templateName = Default
    templateRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:theme/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/
    }
    partialRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:theme/Resources/Private/Partials/Page/
    }
    layoutRootPaths {
        0 = EXT:theme/Resources/Private/Layouts/Page/
    }

    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        10 {
            table = tt_content
            orderBy = sorting

            as = contentElements
        }
    }
}

I included both EXT:fluid_styled_content and EXT:form in the backend root template:

But the Content element looks like this:

The TypoScript files for EXT:fluid_styled_content and EXT:form are imported, but the CSS is not used.

Just to be sure: EXT:theme is installed/activated?

Yes, it is installed with composer

Did you check the "Network" tab in the Developer area in your browser (STRG+I)? There you can see if the system checks for CSS files and what status code comes back.

There are some challenges to consider, in your answer it keeps open if or how far you realized them.
Internal structure of your theme extension.
Extension need some files mandatory, essentially these are:

ext_emconf.php
composer.json

While many files are optional, there structure and naming is predefined nevertheless. Seeing your code, you seem to have recognized this correctly concerning

EXT:theme/Resources/Private/
EXT:theme/Resources/Public/

Concerning your TypoScript, it's certainly possible to note it directly in the backend TypoScript record of your root page, else you've to assure that it's noted in the file EXT:theme/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.typoscript that has to be included. Usually that's done like the other files you included in the TypoScript record, it's possible though to include it differently, this would be without choice and always.
Let's assume you make it optional, like recommended, then the required code in the file EXT:theme/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template,php has to be:
<?php

defined('TYPO3') || die();

call_user_func(function() {
    /**
     * Temporary variables
     */
    $extensionKey = 'theme';

    /**
     * Default TypoScript for Theme
     */
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addStaticFile(
        $extensionKey,
        'Configuration/TypoScript',
        'Theme Setup'
    );
}

Having defined TypoScript and the inclusion requires you then to select the template in the backend TypoScript record like the other setups you selected. As you might override some settings in your theme, select the theme as last inclusion of the list.
Furthermore you've to provide all the defined directories and files you referenced in your TypoScript.
Additionally you've to include one or more Backend-Layouts so that you get the different positions for colPos.
The whole file structure, including further files, is explained in the documentation which you can find here: Filestructure of TYPO3 extensions, note that many files are optional.
Installation of a TYPO3 extension via composer
Assumed, that you extension is not available in a public repository I explain the way how to reference it as a "local repository", note that it should be managed with git (on gihub, gitlab, ...) or another version management solution, but that is not required to get it running in TYPO3.
In your installation directory for TYPO3 create a sub-directory packages and move your theme extension inside this.
Then the structure looks like this:
[dir]  config
[dir]  packages
[dir]  packages/theme
[dir]  public
[dir]  var
[dir]  vendor
[file] composer.json
[file] composer.lock


In the file composer.json you've to make your local repository of the theme extension available, add these lines in the json structure:
    "repositories": {
      "sitepackage": {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "packages/*"
      }
    },

Here you find the in-depth explanation of a path as repository.
Furthermore, in the theme extension, the composer.json file has to include  the required name, which consists of vendor and extension-name. It's explained in the TYPO3 documentation which I linked above at the end of the first chapter concerning all the files inside extensions.
So this command (replace VENDOR by your vendor-name) should install the theme in TYPO3:
composer require VENDOR/theme:"@dev"

Having installed the extension the option to include the TypoScript of the theme extension should become available, else clear the cache ...
vendor/bin/typo3 cache:flush

and try again.
There are many things that can be misunderstood or go wrong, so feel welcome to detail your question if anything is not working (or if I got your question completely wrong  ).
